# Create an array of UIImages from camera roll

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I would like to get all of the images from the camera roll and create an array of UIImages from them.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for about a day now and I've gotten nowhere. I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve *only* items from the Camera Roll. It appears that all of the samples that I've seen all enumerate over all of the photo albums. I might be wrong about that though.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You mean picking array of images using UIImagePickerController?

Comment: I'm making something similar to the Photo's application in iOS but I can't figure out how to obtain individual photo album data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ALAssetsLibrary? like this:

```
assets = [[NSMutableArray array] init]; // Prepare array to have retrieved images by Assets Library.

void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(asset != NULL) {
        [assets addObject:asset]; 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self insertArray];
        });
    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
};

// Create instance of the Assets Library.
library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos // Retrieve the images saved in the Camera roll.
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Failed.");
                     }];
```

that'll nab them. then do this to render them (this is wicked hacky. you'll want to import them as needed and not all at once like this, or you'll run into memory issues and crash)

```
-(void) insertArray {

int i = assetCount++;

if (i>20) {
    return;
}

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[assets objectAtIndex:i] defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
CGSize cSize = CGSizeMake(75,75);
UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
UIImage *resizedimage = (UIImage *)[largeimage resizedImage:cSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:resizedimage];
if((i>0)&&(i%4 == 0)){
    rowCount++;
}

colCount = i%4;
newView.frame = CGRectMake(4+(colCount*(75+4)), 4+(rowCount*(75+4)), 75, 75);

[sv addSubview:newView];
[sv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 85+(rowCount*(75+4)))];

NSLog(@"sv frame size is %@ and i is %i", NSStringFromCGRect(sv.frame), i);


}
```

Comment: oops... i forgot that i used a the UIImage+Resize library here: [http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Comment: Hi

void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
}

its not entering this loop